# "ReflectionException Function () does not exist" when trying to setup authentication in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8

I'm having some trouble getting authentication working 100% in Laravel (all views seem to work so far except for "home") and was hoping to get some assistance from the Laravel experts out there.

#### A bit of background info:

- PHP Version: **7.3.11**
- Laravel Version: **8.13.0**
- Used **Composer** to build the ui scaffolding (`composer require laravel/ui`)
- Used the **Bootstrap** ui option (`php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`)

#### The issue

As mentioned above, I seem to be able to access all of the generated authentication views so far  (login, register & the password reset views), however after registering with a dummy account I get the following error when trying to access the "home" view:

> ReflectionException

> Function () does not exist

The Stack trace is pointing to the following file:
"vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteSignatureParameters.php:23":

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Routing;

use Illuminate\Support\Reflector;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use ReflectionFunction;
use ReflectionMethod;

class RouteSignatureParameters
{
    /**
     * Extract the route action's signature parameters.
     *
     * @param  array  $action
     * @param  string|null  $subClass
     * @return array
     */
    public static function fromAction(array $action, $subClass = null)
    {
        $parameters = is_string($action['uses'])
                        ? static::fromClassMethodString($action['uses'])
                        : (new ReflectionFunction($action['uses']))->getParameters();

        return is_null($subClass) ? $parameters : array_filter($parameters, function ($p) use ($subClass) {
            return Reflector::isParameterSubclassOf($p, $subClass);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the parameters for the given class / method by string.
     *
     * @param  string  $uses
     * @return array
     */
    protected static function fromClassMethodString($uses)
    {
        [$class, $method] = Str::parseCallback($uses);

        if (! method_exists($class, $method) && Reflector::isCallable($class, $method)) {
            return [];
        }

        return (new ReflectionMethod($class, $method))->getParameters();
    }
}
```

With the following line (line 23) being highlighted as the error:

`: (new ReflectionFunction($action['uses']))->getParameters();`

And here are the routes used in the "web.php" file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome', ['pageTitle' => 'Home']);
});

Route::get('/services', function () {
    return view('services', ['pageTitle' => 'Services']);
});

Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return view('contact', ['pageTitle' => 'Contact']);
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', ['pageTitle' => 'Client Dashboard'], [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

After a bit of googling I've learnt that the method I'm trying to use to setup authentication has been deprecated and it is now advised to use **Jetstream** or **Fortify**, however I also found a few examples of people still managing to use this old method in their projects:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuGBzmHlINQ

As this is my first ever Laravel project I was really trying to just stick with the basics and not over complicate things for myself which is why I chose not to use **Jetstream** or **Fortify** and tried to stick to this older approach of setting up authentication. However I've been stuck on this for a couple of hours now and have not been able to figure out what's going wrong which is why I'm now seeking some help with it.

Happy to provide extra details/project code if needed - any help I can get with this would be really appreciated.

Btw, this also happens to be my first ever post on StackOverflow so any feedback on my question or advice on how I can improve it would also be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

adb

Comment: Welcome to SO ... can you provide your routes?

Comment: Thanks @lagbox, just updated the question to include the routes :)

Comment: your last route is not right, `get` only takes 2 arguments ... just pass the first and third from what you have

Comment: @lagbox, you are a legend! Can't believe it was that simple - thanks so much for your help mate

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adjust your last route to include some type of 'action', by removing that second argument (as it only takes 2 arguments):

```
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same issue with me here is my web.php code for the route is

**Wrong**

```
Route::post('postformdata',[PostFormDataController::class],'postData');
```

**Correct**

```
Route::post('postformdata',[PostFormDataController::class,'postData']);
```

> The issue is that I am not writing the function name '**postData**'in the square
> brackets "[]" as I have written them outside the square brackets You
> can check in the Correct code so be careful in writing the Route.

*Maybe someone encountered the same issue as me so it will be helpful for them*

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the web.php file.

I was getting the same error when using the following route:

**Route::post('/delete/{id}',[AdminController::class],'destroyProduct');**

Changing the route using this code fixed the problem:

***Route::post('/delete/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@destroyProduct');***

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when making a simple route.

```
Route::get("/test", [ListPagesController::class, "index"]);
```

This was my code in the web.php file and I was routing my blade file in views via the controller.
When I later redirected it directly to web.php this way without using a controller, the problem was resolved.

```
Route::get("/test", function () {return view("main");});
```

I don't quite understand why but the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You Should add it in line 2 web.php
use App\Http\Controllers\YourControllerName;

Answer (score 0):

For me, I changed:

```
Route::get('/branch/',  [Controller::class, 'get_branch_list'])->name('branch');
```

To:

```
Route::get('/branch/',  'Controller@get_branch_list')->name('branch');
```