# Symfony 5 Project: Exception has occurred. ReflectionException: Function include() does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, xdebug

I get this error no matter what I call in my project. There are no problems without Xdebug. When I turn Xdebug on I always get:

> Exception has occurred. ReflectionException: Function include() does not exist

This is the line that gives the error:

```php
$caller = isset($frame['class']) ? new \ReflectionMethod($frame['class'], $frame['function']) : new \ReflectionFunction($frame['function']);
```

It's in `ExceptionCaster.php`. This is a Symfony file and not one of my own ones.

I use:

```
Symfony 5.1.8
PHP 8.0.2 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2021 15:14:20) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

The route I am calling looks like this:

```yml
manage_article:
   path:      /manage_article
   defaults:  { _controller: \App\Controller\ManageArticleController::manageArticleAction }
```

Is Xdebug not compatible with PHP 8? Or with my version of Symfony? Or what else could be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ReflectionException Function () does not exist" when trying to setup authentication in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64734748/reflectionexception-function-does-not-exist-when-trying-to-setup-authentica)

Comment: Don't think so. Its laravel. But I will add the route I am calling above.

Answer (score 1):

Xdebug 3.0.x is compatible with PHP 8.0 (and also PHP 7.2-7.4).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
As soon as I remove the monolog bundle everything works as expected.

Hopefully this will be fixed in the future.